# Proxing S3 request for autherization using nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, lua, openresty

I am trying to access private S3 from an EC2 machine but using curl only.
So I am trying to create a proxy server using nginx and lua which will call metadata apis and get the authorization token and set the headers in proxy_pass.

```
 location  /download/ {
      set $date  '';
      set $token  '';
      set $authorization '';

      content_by_lua_block {

        % some code %

        ngx.var.date = date;
        ngx.var.token = awsToken;
        ngx.var.authorization = authorization;

      }

      proxy_set_header Date $date;
      proxy_set_header X-AMZ-Security-Token  $token;
      proxy_set_header Authorization  $authorization;
      proxy_pass "https://nisingla-ethos.s3.amazonaws.com/";
    }
```

However, when i check date varible outside of content_by_lua_block, its value is not set.
Can someone help me with the issue.

PS: I have tried other method of using bucket policy and vpc endpoint but due to some constraint they will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Both `content_by_lua_block` and `proxy_pass` are processed in Content phase.
Nginx does call only one such directive.

You may use `access_by_lua_block` or `set_by_lua_block`.